# Documentation of Moses (statistical machine translation) mose.ini file format?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, machine-translation, moses

Is there any documentation of the moses.ini format for Moses? Running moses at the command line without arguments returns available feature names but not their available arguments. Additionally, the structure of the .ini file is not specified in the manual that I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is that the file contains settings that will be used by the translation model. Thus, the documentation of values and options in `moses.ini` should be looked up in the Moses feature specifications.

Here are some excerpt I found on the Web about `moses.ini`.

In the [Moses Core](http://ec.europa.eu/information_society/apps/projects/logos/7/288487/080/deliverables/001_MosesSpecificationAres20132942326.pdf), we have some details:

> `7.6.5 moses.ini`
>  All feature functions are specified in the `[feature]` section. It should be in the format:
>   `* Feature-name key1=value1` `key2=value2` .... 
> For example, `KENLM factor=0 order=3 num-features=1 lazyken=0 path=file.lm.gz`

Also, there is a hint on how to print basic statistics about all components mentioned in the moses.ini.

> Run the script
>   `analyse_moses_model.pl moses.ini`
>   This can be useful to set the order of mapping steps to avoid explosion of translation options or just to check that the model components are as big/detailed as we expect.

In the [Center for Computational Language and EducAtion Research (CLEAR)](https://clear.colorado.edu/CompSemWiki/index.php/Moses) Wiki, there is a sample file with some documentation:

> **Parameters**
>
> It is recommended to make an `.ini` file to storage all of your setting.
>
> `input-factors`
>   - Using factor model or not
>   `mapping`
>   - To use LM in memory (T) or read the file in hard disk directly (G)
>   `ttable-file`
>   - Indicate the num. of source-factor, num. of target-factor, num of score, and
>   the path to translation table file 
>   `lmodel-file`
>   - Indicate the type using for LM (0:SRILM, 1:IRSTLM), using factor number, the order (n-gram) of LM, and the path to language model file

If it is not enough, there is another description on [this page, see "Decoder configuration file" section](http://stp.lingfil.uu.se/~ch/lab7.html)

> The sections
>   `[ttable-file]` and `[lmodel-file]` contain pointers to the phrase table
>   file and language model file, respectively. You may disregard the
>   numbers on those lines. For the time being, it's enough to know that
>   **the last one of the numbers in the language model specification is the
>   order of the n-gram model**.
>
> The configuration file also contains some feature weights. Note that
>   the `[weight-t]` section has 5 weights, one for each feature contained
>   in the phrase table.
>
> The `moses.ini` file created by the training process **will not work with
>   your decoder without modification** because it relies on a language
>   model library that is not compiled into our decoder. In order to make
>   it work, open the moses.ini file and find the language model
>   specification in the line immediately after the `[lmodel-file]` heading.
>   The first number on this line will be `0`, which stands for SRILM.
>   Change it into `8` and leave the rest of the line untouched. Then your
>   configuration should work.

Comment: Additional documentation for the translation table can be found here: http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=FactoredTraining.ScorePhrases